# How can Display Suite be used with Book module links?

Tags: navigation, display-suite, nodes

After settings some node types to use Display Suite I have noticed those which are in Books don't show the book links at the bottom of the page.

Is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 0):

you've to activate the full display to show the book navigation field on Display Suite display settings.

There is only a problem: the book navigation links are always rendered after the comment form. I know it was a known bug some months ago but I don't know if it has been fixed recently.